# Change Specific Items Color in CListCtrl?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, mfc

I want to change the color of all Target Name to red Include in Name1, Name2, and Name3. And every test name to black or its default color. 
lvColumn type is LVCOLUMN.
Any Idea how to do that?................

```
lvColumn.mask = LVCF_FMT | LVCF_TEXT | LVCF_WIDTH;
    lvColumn.fmt = LVCFMT_LEFT;
    lvColumn.cx = 120;
    lvColumn.pszText = "Name1";
    m_szList.InsertColumn(0, &lvColumn);

    lvColumn.mask = LVCF_FMT | LVCF_TEXT | LVCF_WIDTH;
    lvColumn.fmt = LVCFMT_LEFT;
    lvColumn.cx = 75;
    lvColumn.pszText = "Name2";
    m_szList.InsertColumn(1, &lvColumn);

    lvColumn.mask = LVCF_FMT | LVCF_TEXT | LVCF_WIDTH;
    lvColumn.fmt = LVCFMT_LEFT;
    lvColumn.cx = 80;
    lvColumn.pszText = "Name3";
    m_szList.InsertColumn(2, &lvColumn);


    LVITEM lvItem;
    int nItem;

    lvItem.mask = LVIF_TEXT;
    lvItem.iItem = 0;
    lvItem.iSubItem = 0;
    lvItem.pszText = "Test1";
    nItem = m_szList.InsertItem(&lvItem);

    m_szList.SetItemText(nItem, 1, "Target");
    m_szList.SetItemText(nItem, 2, "Test3");

    lvItem.mask = LVIF_TEXT;
    lvItem.iItem = 1;
    lvItem.iSubItem = 0;
    lvItem.pszText = "Test2";
    nItem = m_szList.InsertItem(&lvItem);

    m_szList.SetItemText(nItem, 1, "Test1");
    m_szList.SetItemText(nItem, 2, "Target");

    lvItem.mask = LVIF_TEXT;
    lvItem.iItem = 2;
    lvItem.iSubItem = 0;
    lvItem.pszText = "Target";
    nItem = m_szList.InsertItem(&lvItem);

    m_szList.SetItemText(nItem, 1, "Test1");
    m_szList.SetItemText(nItem, 2, "Test2");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to handle the `NM_CUSTOMDRAW` message and change the text color in that handler.

Comment: SIr, Please Help me do that. I don't know how to do?

Comment: Please check this article: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/79/Neat-Stuff-to-Do-in-List-Controls-Using-Custom-Dra

Comment: Sir, In that project they set whole line to red. But in my case the target name is set in different place. How to do the same thing here?

Comment: You need to check `pLVCD->nmcd.iSubItem`. That is your column. Check the definition of `NMLVCUSTOMDRAW` structure at https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/bb774778

Comment: Don't be weird Mike. You have enough links and information to do this exact task. You should read that first.

Comment: Sir, i try too much always fail. Please Help?

Comment: The code in the sample just shows what to do. Just read the part "A Little Less Simple Example" in http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/79/Neat-Stuff-to-Do-in-List-Controls-Using-Custom-Dra

Comment: Another way is to use a specialized CListCtrl class, like this one: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/213901/ListCtrlEx-control

Comment: Show us the code which you tried so that we can help you achieve/resolve.